# The $y$ coordinate when rotating around the $x$-axis.

Tags: geometry

This might be a simple question, but my maths a bit rusty so I'll post it here. I'm looking to get a $y$ coordinate after rotating around the $x$ axis. For example I would like to know the $y$ coordinate after rotating around the $x$ axis with a rotation of $10$ degrees. I have no knowledge of a $z$ coordinate. I thought the equation $$\frac{y'+z\sin(p)\cos(p)}{\cos(p)}$$ would work but I don't have a $z$ value. Is there an easy way to compute this point? An example question would be nice, for example I have a point $(14,10)$ and rotating around the $x$-axis at $10$ degrees. How would this be solved?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you say you have no knowledge of a z coordinate, can you clarify? Do you mean a z coordinate does not exist, or that it does and you don't know what it is?

Answer (score 0):

In the standard basis in $3$-space, a matrix for the rotation of angle $\theta$ about the $x$-axis looks like this:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\
0&\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\\
\end{bmatrix}$

(This matrix is acting on column vectors.)

Notice the $x$ coordinate is left fixed, and the lower right hand $2\times 2$ block is a rotation in the $y-z$ plane.

So, find cosine and sine of 10 degrees, transform your vector, and examine the resulting $y$ coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Just use $ z=0 $. So instead of $(x, 14)$ think of it as $(x, 14 , 0)$.

Rotating $(x, 14 , 0)$ by $10$ degrees around the $x$ axis it becomes 
$ (x, 14 \cos(10^o ) , -14 \sin(10^o) ) $

Now you don't have an $z$ coordinate it just becomes $ (x, 14 \cos(10^o) , 0 ) $.

Be aware that you can use this method only by starting from the original.
rotating by $20^o$ does not give the same result as rotating twice by $10^o $ this way